# Jupyter notebook browser crashed but running in command prompt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was scraping the web using jupyter notebook and it had been running for 20 hours. Now, because it was taking up a lot of ram, the browser eventually crashed however the command prompt instance is still running. Is there a way to retrieve the browser contents back with the data which is already scraped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are out of luck here, the one thing you can do is check `.ipynb_checkpoints/` if you can get a recent checkpoint.